# Energy of an object near a black hole

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, black-holes

I'm starting to read about black holes and am confused with some concepts. So here is one (simple?) question that I can't wrap my head around: What would be the energy (Joules) released by a 1kg mass near a black hole? Would you use the regular E=mc2 for this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a 1 kg mass (m) is not moving in relation to the black hole (of mass M) the energy of the 1 kg mass could be written as: $$E=mc^2\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}}$$

If you Taylor expand you see that you get:
$$E \approx mc^2-GMm/r$$
where -GMm/r is the classical potential energy.